# Should dependent objects be private in spring boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Is it mandatory to declare the dependent fields *private* in spring boot?
For example :

```
class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    EmpService empService
}
```

```
class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private EmpService empService  
}
```

Which one is correct and why?

Both are working fine and I would like to know if any difference is there between default and private dependent field except the access modifier differences

Comment: Its a good practise to declare them private but its not mandatory though.

Comment: _"I would like to know if any difference is there between default and private dependent field except the access modifier differences"_ - default is package private, so any class in the same package can modify the field if it's not private.

Answer (score 1):

Either. There is no requirement from Spring creators to make it `private` or not. The autowiring works regardless of the visibility modifiers.

There is though a good practice to [encapsulate](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) the fields. The framework choice is not relevant. It is a common practice to define the autowired fields as `private`, though it is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not mandatory at all. It's just good practice to make them private. Though at times you may get scope errors when you annotate private methods with the `@Bean` annotation.
But for the injection, encapsulation is optional.